# Running Python 3.6 on Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

Feels like this is a bit of a rookie question, but I figured I'd ask anyway.

I have some homegrown packages that are stuck on python 3.6 and I want to update Airflow, which runs them. This means I'm stuck on the highest version of Airflow that supports 3.6 right? Can I work around this using an env or something?

Comment: Could you add some details? You need possibility to upgrade `airflow` and `python` version but also and you need to run some `PythonOperator` using `python3.6` and specific `requirements`?

Comment: what about running your program that uses a homegrown packages in a docker image and run a airflow Docker operator that runs the image?

Comment: Without knowing more details about your Airlfow's environment (do you have full control over it? is it managed by IE: Google? How are those Python packages used? In Airflow? Just in tasks?) it's a bit hard to give an answer. If those packages are just going to be used in tasks (not in the Airflow machinery itself) besides what @LucasM.Uriarte suggests about running your them in a Docker image which would probably be best, I would like to point to an `ExternalPythonOperator` or a `PythonVirtualenvOperator` where you can specify a path to the Python interpreter or a different version of Python.

Comment: Thanks! I am running a custom package that is stuck on 3.6 until we can deprecate the whole thing. I think running docker on my docker might be the solution then. Additional details, it's self hosted/managed and the package is used in the tasks. I will explore the PythonOperators you supplied.

Comment: Additionally, I am using the KubernetesOperator already.